# add/remove class on click and on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got 2 rows of html.

One row contains plain html and another row contains ul li lists.

First case:

On page load I want to change the text color of row one depending on which li is active.

Second Case

On click any li from second row, I would like to change the color of first row html depending on what  data I have clicked in second row.

My code

First row

```
<div class="horizontal-link">
    <div class="test">
         <h4 data-id="1">Text 1</h4> <!--So on page load I would like to change the color to red as related with row 2 ul li) -->

    </div>
    <div class="test">
         <h4 data-id="2">Text 2</h4>

    </div>
</div>
```

Second Row

```
<ul>
    <li class="tab active" data-id="1">Text 1</li>
    <li class="tab" data-id="2">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried and created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/v1v1tqzs/) as demo:

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your nice contribution.

Comment: What about my fiddle . I have updated your `fiddle` . Please check @Raj

Comment: Thanks Tushar for your help.Really appreciated. I have voted up your post. Actually I found Anton's answer more efficient. :)

Comment: Pleasure @Raj No Problem !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) or [attribute-selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) to check the data-id like this

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    //Adds class on load depending on which is active
    $('.test h4[data-id="'+$('ul li.active').data('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
    //Adds class on click
    $('li.tab').on('click',function(){
        $('.test h4').removeClass('active');
        $that = $(this);
        $('.test h4').filter(function(){
            return $(this).data('id')==$that.data('id')
        }).addClass('active');
    //removes class on clickable li and adds to clicked
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.test h4.active {
    color:red;
}
```

You need to change the css so it checked the h4 if has the class active

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v1v1tqzs/27/)

Comment: Awesome simply brilliant solution.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can either change text color of `div` or `h4` by adding `active` class.

For `div` with `active` class use below jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    var id = $('ul').find('.active').attr('data-id');
    $('.horizontal-link h4[data-id="'+id+'"]').closest('.test').addClass('active');


    $("li.tab").click(function () {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $('.horizontal-link h4[data-id="'+id+'"]').closest('.test').addClass('active');

     });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v1v1tqzs/25/)**

For `h4`, you need to change CSS like below

CSS :

```
.test h4.active {
    color:red;
}
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    var id = $('ul').find('.active').attr('data-id');
    $('.horizontal-link h4[data-id="'+id+'"]').addClass('active');


    $("li.tab").click(function () {
        $('.horizontal-link h4').removeClass('active');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $('.horizontal-link h4[data-id="'+id+'"]').addClass('active');

     });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v1v1tqzs/12/)**

Answer (score 1):

Look at the JS fiddle here. I hope this will help you.,

Updated jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function ($) {

        var id = $('ul').find('.active').attr('data-id');

        $('.horizontal-link h4[data-id='+id+']').addClass('active');

        $("li.tab").click(function () {
            $('.horizontal-link h4').removeClass('active');
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $('.horizontal-link h4[data-id='+id+']').addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

JS Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/v1v1tqzs/34/

Answer (score 1):

There is a change in your **CSS** :-

```
.test .active {
    color:red;
 }
```

you wrote it as `.test.active` . There should be a **gap** . That's why **on page load** the `color:red` was not getting implemented .

**[YOUR UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v1v1tqzs/41/):**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var id = $('ul').find('.active').attr('data-id');

$('.horizontal-link h4').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-id') == id) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return;
    }
});

$("li.tab").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.horizontal-link h4').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
    $('.horizontal-link h4').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-id') == id) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return;
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , code can be optimized

HTML:

```
<div class="horizontal-link">
    <div class="test">
         <h4 class = "1" data-id="1">Text 1</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="test">
         <h4 class = "2" data-id="2">Text 2</h4>

    </div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li class="tab active" data-id="1">Text 1</li>
    <li class="tab" data-id="2">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
.test.active {
    color:red;
}
.tab {
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul li.tab {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px
}
.active {
    color:red;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var id = $('ul').find('.active').attr('data-id');

    if ($('.horizontal-link h4').attr('data-id') == id) {
        $('.'+id).addClass('active');
    }

});

$(".tab").click(function () {
    $(".tab").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.horizontal-link h4').removeClass('active');
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.'+id).addClass('active');

});
```